# ssl error invalid or self-signed certificate magento image upload

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

ssl error invalid or self-signed certificate magento image upload

Any have solution for this error.Please rectify my problem

Comment: Check this solution: magento.stackexchange.com/a/76146/1916

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because of .htaccess password protected website. Removing temporarily the password protection fixed the problem.

Comment: What should I remove password protection from .htaccess file?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the cookies. You have a set of cookies with your already authenticated backend. The flash component cannot see that, so it tries to connect to the backend's upload script, but apache will ask the flash component for a password, which is not handled well in the flash component. Then you will get the error message. Just remove (at least temporarily) the Auth related lines from your htaccess file and then it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your message. I don't know what's going on my server but it does work in Firefox & Chrome. It works fine in Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 1):

In the Base URL fields you should enter the unsecure (regular) web site URL and the web site URL for the SSL connections. You can leave the other values unchanged, as they will be set automatically by the script after you enter the Base URL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this only happened on staging magento servers.  They had an HTACCESS file that was whitelisted for the IP and both had the HTTP site listed in the "Secure" and "Unsecure" section of the magento web configuration.  Using Firefox, it would fail every single time, trying to upload a product image.  The only solution that worked reliably each time was to install and use Chrome. 
For some reason, that seemed to solve our issue throughout all of our servers.  This error never showed up on our production server that had a real SSL installed.