# SSL Error: Invalid or self-signed certificate - Magento image upload in products

Tags: php, magento

I get `SSL Error: Invalid or self-signed certificate` error while uploading image to the product.
I am able to **upload images easily to categories**,, but I am not able to **upload images to products**..

and yes please dont mark as duplicate I already have checked this [Magento - Error while uploading images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785714/magento-error-while-uploading-images)... but it doesn't help me out.. and I also checked this question too... [ssl error invalid or self-signed certificate magento image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245365/ssl-error-invalid-or-self-signed-certificate-magento-image-upload)

as james suggested **it works on chrome**.. but I really want to know how to enable also on **firefox** as my client uses firefox only..

Comment: I had the same issue in Firefox but when i used chrome i was able to upload images

Comment: @James hey thanks so much.. that worked.. but do you know why that was happening???

Comment: i am not sure why it is happening. I think R.S answer would help you. You can also look up to change `localhost` to `localhost.com`

Comment: Check this solution: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76146/1916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the self-signed certificate (magento uses a flash plugin to upload product images)

See

[(IE) Installing a Self-Signed Certificate as a Trusted Root CA](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)

[How do I configure OS X to use my self-signed SSL certificate?](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/how-do-i-configure-os-x-to-use-my-self-signed-ssl-certificate-268.html)

**If you are using your base url as `http://localhost`**

> NOTE:
>
> Magento requires itself to be installed on a host name with at least
>   one period ‘.’ in it, therefore installing to `http://localhost` doesn’t
>   work. (Having installed to //localhost, I was unable to get it running
>   even after the following changes. In the end I had to reinstall using
>   the new host name which then worked fine.)

[[wiki] Installing on PC-based localhost using XAMPP and WAMP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp)

[[wiki] Installing on OSX-based localhost](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing-magento-on-mac-os-x-server-10-4-9)

Comment: Please mark that I am using this on my localhost (windows 32bit),, and yes I also have another magento site on my localhost and I am able to upload images on that site..

Comment: no.. I have turned of `secure URLs` from the `magento backend` and no it's `http://localhost`...

Comment: I put `https://localhost` and when it asked for `get certificate` I saved the certificate.. but that doesnt solved my error..

Comment: I already have checked it .. I have put my `id address` as the path.. it was `http://192.168.0.10/`.. but it also didnt helped..

Comment: What I would recommend is to update you host file  with (something like) `http://192.168.0.10 www.mymagentosite.com` then update you magento base urls with `www.mymagentosite.com`

Comment: this is my hosts file.. but it doesnt redirects to the URL...
`192.168.0.10             www.mymagento.com`

Comment: What OS are you running... also trying doing a ping www.mymagento.com .... take a look @ http://serverfault.com/questions/9050/how-to-refresh-hosts-file-without-rebooting

Comment: why does this answer marked as solution? did it work for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You may easily setup your Magento store to be accessed with SSL. For that purpose login the administration area and navigate to “System” -> Configuration. From the left side menu select “Web”. You will be present with options to define the secured and unsecured URLs of your store.

In the “Secure” section you will only have to change the “Base URL” from:

http://yourdomain.com/

to

https://yourdomain.com/

If your Magento store is installed in a subfolder of your account you must add the name of that folder after the last slash.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as Nishant and my hosting service provider gave me a link to check what exactly was creating the issue and we found that a google font used in css was..

**https://www.whynopadlock.com/**

Hope it would help someone else like me to resolve the issue.